# Dotcloud multiple services

Tags: dotcloud

I'm new to dotcloud, and am confused about how multiple services work together.

my yaml build file is:

```
www:
  type: python
db:
  type: postgresql
worker:
  type: python-worker
broker:
  type: rabbitmq
```

And my supervisord file contains commands to start django celery & celerycam.

When I push my code out to my app, I can see that both the www & worker services start up their own instances of celery & celery cam, and also for example the log files will be different. This makes sense (although isn't made very clear in the dotcloud documentation in IMO - the documentation talks about setting up a worker service, but not how to combine that with other services), but does raise the question of how to configure an application where the python service mainly serves the web page, whilst the python worker service works on background tasks, eg: celery.

The [dotcloud documentation daemon](http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/daemons/) makes mention of this:

> "However, you should be aware that when you scale your application,
>   the cron tasks will be scheduled in all scaled instances – which is
>   probably not what you need! So in many cases, it will still be better
>   to use a separate service.
>
> Similarly, a lot of (non-worker) services already run Supervisor, so
>   you can run additional background jobs in those services. Then again,
>   remember that those background jobs will run in multiple instances if
>   you scale your application. Moreover, if you add background jobs to
>   your web service, it will get less resources to serve pages, and your
>   performance will take a significant hit."

How do you configure dotcloud & your application to run just the webserver on one service, and background tasks on the worker service? Would you scale workers by increasing the concurrency setting in celery (and scaling the one service vertically), by adding extra worker services, or both?

Would you do this so that firstly the webserver service doesn't have to use resources in processing background tasks, and secondly so that you could scale the worker services independently of the webserver service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two tricks.
First you could use different [approots](http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/build-file/#specifying-the-root-directory-of-a-service) for your www and worker services to separate the code they will run:

```
www:
  type: python
  approot: frontend
# ...
worker:
  type: python-worker
  approot: backend
# ...
```

Second, since your [postinstall](http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/hooks/#post-install) script is different for each approot, you can copy a file out to become the correct supervisord.conf for that particular service.

You may also want to look at the dotCloud tutorial and sample code for django-celery.

/Andy